# How can I run windows command promt from java application?

Tags: java, user-interface, cmd, swig, processbuilder

At the moment I try to make application with GUI. This application have to run cmd with some commands. I am trying to do it. I want to realize action(When I push button "search"-command promt is openning). I tried to use ProcessBuilder to achieve the target but I dont have result. As you can see below, I try to run cmd with "dir" command. I tried do without running some commands, but CMD is steal not running. As result we don't see window and process in task manager.
This is my code:

```
    package sys.tool;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
//Создаем поля

public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
    private JLabel lcn = new JLabel("Enter computer name:");
    private JTextField icn = new JTextField("", 5);
    private JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    private JLabel lun = new JLabel("Enter user name:");
    private  JTextField iun = new JTextField("", 5);
    private JLabel empty = new JLabel("");


public MainWindow (){
    super("SysAdminTool");
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 700 , 90);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2 , 1, 1));
    container.add(lcn);
    container.add(icn);

    container.add(lun);
    container.add(iun);

    container.add(empty);
    search.addActionListener(new SearchEventListener());
    container.add(search); //this is button
}

class  SearchEventListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "dir C:\\Users"); \\here I try to run cmd with command "dir"
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run command on OS.

```
String command = "command of the operating system";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: I did it earlier, but when I try to build project, command exec highlighted red color and this error appeared:"Error:(38, 55) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown". I put this code in class SearchEventListener: <code>class SearchEventListener implements ActionListener{ public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){ String command = "cmd.exe"; Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) </code>

Answer (score 1):

This code outputs the result of the dir command to the console:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Commander {

    private static final String CHAR_SET_NAME_WINDOWS = "windows-1251";
    private static final String CHAR_SET_UTF = "utf8";
    private static final String CHAR_SET_CP = "cp866";

    private static final String COMMAND = "cmd.exe /c dir";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runCommand(COMMAND, CHAR_SET_NAME_WINDOWS);
    }

    private static void runCommand(String command, String charsetName) {

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            // Get input streams
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), charsetName));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream(), charsetName));

            // Read command standard output
            String s;
            System.out.println("Standard output: ");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // Read command errors
            System.out.println("Standard error: ");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.